# Please make sure your Heroku API Key is configured correctly in the deployment configuration

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, codeship

I am trying to get loader.io to work with codeship for my heroku app. This is the error that I am receiving:

```
heroku-cli: Installing CLI... 22.45MB/22.45MB
    The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP
    verb (i.e. `GET` vs. `POST`), and did you specify your intended version
    with the `Accept` header?
The application "URL FOR HEROKU" can't be accessed. Please make sure your Heroku API Key is configured correctly in the deployment configuration.
```

I have already added the ssh keys, but I am still getting this error. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an error when deploying to Heroku, probably the API key  or the app name you used is invalid (notice that you don't use ssh keys, but the Heroku API key, as described [here on Codeship docs](https://documentation.codeship.com/continuous-deployment/deployment-to-heroku/#step-4---deployment-configuration))

Also, I noticed you used the term "URL TO HEROKU", be aware that you should use the app name, not the full URL.